# How to add simple viewcontroller at start up in tabbar application

Tags: iphone, uitabbarcontroller

I was doing great till now with my tabbar application.
But now I have to add one viewcontroller at start of application and based on selection on that view have to go on specific tab of my tabcontroller.

What I thought to do is change my start up in AppDelegate to new viewcontroller instead of tabbarcontroller, which I did like this:

```
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    


// Add the view controller's view to the window and display.
[self.window addSubview:viewController.view];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

return YES;
```

}

And then call a appdelegate method on button click in new startup view to switch to tabbarcontroller, code is:

```
  -(IBAction)btnTab:(id)sender{


 [(AppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] ChangeView];
}
```

//ChangeView method in AppDelegate:

```
 -(void)ChangeView{

[self.window addSubview:tabBarController.view];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

But problem is I can't see my new view with button on startup, just a blank view is coming...any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that your tabBarController is nil.

Comment: My problem in new viewController I created to show as start of my app is not showing up with its labels and buttons!!

Comment: Ok, are you sure that your viewController is not nil?

Comment: Okay, that problem is solved. Could you tell me how to start the selected tab after selection from viewController, for example two tabs I have "First Tab" and "Second Tab", so how to start second tab if second tab button(button in my simple viewController not in tabbar) is pressed?

Comment: see the docs for UITabBarControllerDelegate. implement all the necessary methods in the app delegate.